# Tooltips in React 0.12 problem with empty divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React 0.12 for tooltips in older project. But there is some problem with empty divs. When I go to another page divs stay and their number is constantly increasing.

So probably componentWillUnmount() not working properly ?

I am adding to componentWillUnmount  this React.unmountComponentAtNode(this.wrap);
but it did not help.

code:

```
define(['jquery', 'react'], function ($, React) {
    var body = $('body')[0];

    var TooltipItem = React.createClass({
        displayName: 'TooltipItem',

        getDefaultProps: function () {
            return {
                height: 0
            };
        },

        componentDidMount: function () {
            var newHeight = this.getDOMNode().clientHeight,
                top = this.props.top;

            if (this.props.height !== newHeight) {
                this.setProps({
                    height: newHeight,
                    top: top - newHeight / 2
                });

            }
        },

        render: function () {
            if (!this.props.visible) {
                return React.createElement('div');
            }

            return React.createElement('div', { className: 'tooltip right', role: 'tooltip', style: { opacity: 1, left: this.props.left, top: this.props.top } },
                    React.createElement('div', { className: 'tooltip-arrow' }),
                    React.createElement('div', { className: 'tooltip-inner' },
                        this.props.content
                    )
                );
        }
    });

    return React.createClass({
        displayName: 'Tooltip',


        componentDidMount: function () {
            this.wrap = document.createElement('div');

            body.appendChild(this.wrap);
        },
        componentWillUnmount: function () {
            React.unmountComponentAtNode(this.wrap);
            body.removeChild(this.wrap);
        },

        isVisible: false,

        toggle: function() {
            if (this.isVisible) {
                this.mouseOut();
            } else {
                this.mouseOver();
            }
        },

        mouseOver: function () {
            var node = this.getDOMNode(),
                width = $(node).width(),
                height = $(node).height(),
                offset = $(node).offset();

            this.left = offset.left + width;
            this.top = offset.top + height/2;

            this.isVisible = true;

            React.render(React.createElement(TooltipItem, { content: this.props.content, visible: this.isVisible, left: this.left, top: this.top }), this.wrap);
        },

        mouseOut: function () {
            this.isVisible = false;

            React.render(React.createElement('div', null), this.wrap);
        },

        render: function () {
            var events = {
                onMouseOver: this.mouseOver,
                onMouseOut: this.mouseOut,
                onClick: this.toggle
            };

            return (
                React.createElement('span', events,
                     this.props.children
                )
            );
        }
    });
});
```